# Rewriting with non-equality equivalence-relations using Isabelle simplifier

Tags: isabelle

I would like to use the simplifier to replace subterms that are not equalities. Instead of a generic definition of my problem, I will illustrate this by an example:

Say I have a simple programming language and a Hoare logic on top of it. Say we have if, while, and the sequence operation. Also, we have `denotation` which gives a denotation of a program, and `hoare P c Q`. Below is an example signature in Isabelle/HOL:

```
(* A simple language and Hoare logic *)
typedecl program
typedecl memory
consts
  seq :: "program ⇒ program ⇒ program" (infixl ";" 10) (* c;d: run c, then run d *)
  ifthen :: "(memory ⇒ bool) ⇒ program ⇒ program" (* ifthen e c: run c if e(current_mem)=true *)
  while :: "(memory ⇒ bool) ⇒ program ⇒ program" (* while e c: run c while e(current_mem)=true *)
  denotation :: "program ⇒ memory ⇒ memory"  (* denotation c m: memory after running c, when starting with memory m *)
  hoare :: "(memory ⇒ bool) ⇒ program ⇒ (memory ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool" 
      (* hoare P c Q: if P(current_mem), then after running c, we have Q(current_mem) *)
```

Now it is not true that `(a;b);c = a;(b;c)` (these are different programs), but it does hold that they are denotationally equivalent, i.e., `denotation ((a;b);c)) = denotation (a;(b;c))`.

That means, I should be able to rewrite `a;(b;c)` to `(a;b);c` inside a Hoare triple. For example, I would like to be able to prove

```
lemma "hoare P (while e (a;b;c)) Q ==> hoare P (while e (a;(b;c))) Q"
```

just using the simplifier (`by simp`), given suitable simplification rules.

Logically, the relevant rules would be:

```
lemma "denotation (a;(b;c)) = denotation ((a;b);c)"
lemma "denotation a = denotation b ==> hoare P a Q = hoare P b Q"
lemma "denotation a = denotation b ==> denotation (while e a) = denotation (while e b)"
lemma "denotation a = denotation b ==> denotation (ifthen e a) = denotation (ifthen e b)"
lemma "denotation a = denotation a' ==> denotation b = denotation b' ==> denotation (a;b) = denotation (a';b')"
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be no straightforward way of telling those rules to the simplifier. (More generically, we would like to tell the simplifier in a congruence-rule, that the rewriting below has to be done module a certain equivalence relation, denotational-equivalence in the present example.)

I have found a partial solution to this problem (see my own answer below), but the solution seems like a hack (and I don't know how stable it is), and I wonder whether there is a good way to do it.

I do not mind having to use some ML-code in the process (e.g., writing a simproc), but I would like to avoid to have to reimplement the whole simplifier for rewriting inside Hoare tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isabelle's simplifier does not support rewriting with respect to arbitrary equivalence relations. Fortunately, your rewrites appear to be rather simple, so it may be worth to implement the rewriting in a simproc. Here's the idea:

Write a simproc that triggers on terms of the form `hoare P c Q`. Upon invocation, it sets up a goal of the form `hoare P c Q == ?rhs` and
applies a rule stating that `%c. hoare P c Q` only cares about the equivalence class of its argument, not the concrete element. Then, apply the rewriting rules as introduction rules until the stated goal is solved. This should have instantiated `?rhs` to something of the form `hoare P c' Q`. Test whether `c` and `c'` are alpha-beta-eta-...-equivalent. If so, the simproc fails with `NONE`, otherwise it returns the proven equation.

Here is the bunch of lemmas I would use as a start:

```
definition fun_equiv :: "('a ⇒ 'b) ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool"
where "fun_equiv f x y ⟷ f x = f y"

lemma fun_equiv_refl: "fun_equiv f x x" by(simp add: fun_equiv_def)

lemma hoare_cong_start: (* start rule *)
  "fun_equiv denotation c c' ⟹ hoare P c Q == hoare P' c' Q'"
sorry

lemma while_cong: "fun_equiv denotation c c' ⟹ fun_equiv denotation (while b c) (while b c')" sorry

lemma seq_cong: "⟦ fun_equiv denotation a a'; fun_equiv denotation b b' ⟧ ⟹ fun_equiv denotation (a ; b) (a' ; b')" sorry

lemma if_cong: "fun_equiv denotation c c' ⟹ fun_equiv denotation (ifthen b c) (ifthen b c')" sorry

lemma seq_assoc: "fun_equiv denotation (a ; (b ; c)) (a; b; c)" sorry

lemma ifthen_true: "fun_equiv denotation (ifthen (λm. True) c) c" sorry

lemmas hoare_intros =
  -- ‹rewrites come first, congruences later, reflexivity last›
  ifthen_true seq_assoc
  while_cong if_cong seq_cong
  fun_equiv_refl
```

Since this is a simproc inside the simplifier, you may assume that the command in the invocation is already in normal form w.r.t. the simpset. In your example, the test `%m. m = m` has already been simplified to `%_. True`. Thus, the simproc can focus on just implementing the rewrites for the hoare rules.

A single step of the simproc invocation should do something like the following Isar snippet:

```
schematic_lemma "hoare (λm. P x) (while P (c;(d;e);ifthen (λm. True) (f;g;c))) (λm. True) == ?c"
by(rule hoare_cong_start)(rule hoare_intros)+
```

Since the simplifier iterates the simproc until it does not trigger any more, you should really end up with a normal form.

If your want to support conditional rewrite rules w.r.t. denotational equivalence, the `rule hoare_intros` should be replaced with something that checks the format of the subgoal. If it is not of the form `fun_equiv denotation _ _`, then the simproc should invoke the simplifier recursively (or any other proof method of your choice) rather than try another rule application of `hoare_intros`.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work well. Thanks. I have implemented your suggestion. Due to the character limit for comments I am posting my implementation in a [separate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30598337/2646248).

Answer (score 0):

For a way that seems to work OK, see the attached Isabelle/HOL theory. The idea there is to use conditional simp-rules to simulate cong-rules.

E.g., a congruence rule

```
lemma l1 [cong]: "f a = f b ==> g a = g b"
```

is also a valid conditional simp-rule

```
lemma l2 [simp]: "f a = f b ==> g a = g b"
```

and when Isabelle applies the simp-rule, b will be replaced by a schematic variable, and the simplifier will rewrite "f a = f ?b", which instantiates ?b with a simplification of b.

However, lemma `l2` will make the simplifier loop, because it can be applied to it's own rhs. So instead we can write a rule

```
lemma l3 [simp]: "f_simp a = f_done b ==> g_simp a = g_done b"
```

where `g_simp` and `g_done` are defined to be equal to `g`, but will stop the simplifier from applying the rules in a loop.

A full working example of this idea is in the theory file below.

The problems are:
 - It is a hack. I don't know in which situations it might break down or be incompatible with other things
 - `apply simp` may rewrite partially, so you have to invoke it again to finish rewriting. (See the last lemma in the theory.)

```
theory Test
imports Main
begin

section "Minimal Hoare logic"

(* A simple language and Hoare logic *)
typedecl program
typedecl memory
consts
  seq :: "program ⇒ program ⇒ program" (infixl ";" 10) (* c;d: run c, then run d *)
  ifthen :: "(memory ⇒ bool) ⇒ program ⇒ program" (* ifthen e c: run c if e(current_mem)=true *)
  while :: "(memory ⇒ bool) ⇒ program ⇒ program" (* while e c: run c while e(current_mem)=true *)
  denotation :: "program ⇒ memory ⇒ memory"  (* denotation c m: memory after running c, when starting with memory m *)
  hoare :: "(memory ⇒ bool) ⇒ program ⇒ (memory ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool" 
  (* hoare P c Q: if P(current_mem), then after running c, we have Q(current_mem) *)

(* seq is associative modulo denotational equivalence.
  Thus we should be able to rewrite "a;(b;c)" to "a;b;c"
  within a hoare triple. E.g., the following should be solved with simp: *)
lemma
  assumes "hoare P (while e (a;b;c)) Q"
  shows "hoare P (while e (a;(b;c))) Q"
using assms
oops (* by simp *)

section "A failed attempt"

experiment begin
(* Here a natural approach first which, however, fails. *)

(* A congruence rule for the simplifier. 
   To rewrite a hoare triple "hoare P c Q", 
   we need to rewrite "denotation c". *)

lemma enter [cong]:
  assumes "P==P'" and "Q==Q'"
  assumes "denotation c == denotation c'"
  shows "hoare P c Q == hoare P' c' Q'"
sorry

(* To descend further into subterms, we need a congruence-rule for while. *)
lemma while [cong]: 
  assumes "e=e'"
  and "denotation c == denotation c'"
  shows "denotation (while e c) ≡ denotation (while e' c')"
sorry

(* And we give a simplification rule for the associativity of seq *)
lemma assoc [simp]:
  "denotation (a;(b;c)) = denotation (a;b;c)"
sorry

(* Now we can simplify the lemma from above *)
lemma
  assumes "hoare P (while e (a;b;c)) Q"
  shows "hoare P (while e (a;(b;c))) Q"
using assms by simp

(* Unfortunately, this does not work any more once we add more congruence rules. *)
(* To descend further into subterms, we need a congruence-rule for while. *)
lemma ifthen [cong]: 
  assumes "e=e'"
  and "denotation c == denotation c'"
  shows "denotation (ifthen e c) ≡ denotation (ifthen e' c')"
sorry
(* Warning: Overwriting congruence rule for "Test.denotation" *)

(* Simplifier doesn't work any more because the congruence rule for while was overwritten *)
lemma
  assumes "hoare P (while e (a;b;c)) Q"
  shows "hoare P (while e (a;(b;c))) Q"
using assms 
oops (* by simp *)

end

section {* A working attempt *}

(* Define copies of the denotation-constant, to control the simplifier *)
definition "denotation_simp == denotation"
definition "denotation_done == denotation"

(* A congruence rule for the simplifier. 
   To rewrite a hoare triple "hoare P c Q", 
   we need to rewrite "denotation c".

   This means, the congruence rule should have an assumption
   "denotation c == denotation c'"

   However, to avoid infinite loops with the rewrite rules below,
   we use the logically equivalent assumption
   "denotation_simp c == denotation_done c'"

   This means that we need to configure the rules below rewrite
   "denotation_simp c" into "denotation_done c'" where c' is 
   the simplication of c (module denotational equivalence).
 *)
lemma enter [cong]:
  assumes "P==P'" and "Q==Q'"
  assumes "denotation_simp c == denotation_done c'"
  shows "hoare P c Q == hoare P' c' Q'"
sorry

(* A similar congruence rule for simplifying expressions
  of the form "denotation c". *)
lemma denot [cong]:
  assumes "denotation_simp c == denotation_done c'"
  shows "denotation c == denotation c'"
sorry

(* Now we add a congruence-rule for while.
  Since we saw above that we cannot use several congruence-rules
  with "denotation" as their head,
  we simulate a congruence rule using a simp-rule.

  To rewrite "denotation_simp (while e c)", we need to rewrite
  "denotation_simp c".

  We put denotation_done on the rhs instead of denotation_simp 
  to avoid infinite loops.
*)
lemma while [simp]: 
  assumes "e=e'"
  and "denotation_simp c == denotation_done c'"
  shows "denotation_simp (while e c) ≡ denotation_done (while e' c')"
sorry

(* A pseudo-congruence rule for ifthen *)
lemma ifthen [simp]:
  assumes "e=e'"
  and "denotation_simp c == denotation_done c'"
  shows "denotation_simp (ifthen e c) == denotation_done (ifthen e' c')"
sorry

(* A pseudo-congruence rule for seq *)
lemma seq [simp]:
  assumes "denotation_simp c == denotation_done c'"
  and "denotation_simp d == denotation_done d'"
  shows "denotation_simp (c;d) == denotation_done (c';d')"
sorry

(* Finally, we can state associativity of seq. *)
lemma assoc [simp]:
  "denotation_simp (a;(b;c)) = denotation_simp (a;b;c)"
sorry

(* Finally, since our congruence-rules expect the rewriting to rewrite
  "denotation_simp c" into "denotation_done c'", 
  we need to translate any non-rewritten "denotation_simp" into
  "denotation_done".

  However, a rule "denotation_simp c == denotation_done c" does not work,
  because it could be triggered too early, and block the pseudo-congruence rules above.

  So we only trigger the rule when the current term would not match
  any of the pseudo congruence rules *)
lemma finish [simp]: 
  assumes "NO_MATCH (while e1 c1) a"
  assumes "NO_MATCH (ifthen e2 c2) a"
  assumes "NO_MATCH (c3;d3) a"
  shows "denotation_simp a = denotation_done a"
sorry

(* Testing the simplifier rules *)
lemma
  assumes "hoare P (while e (a;b;c)) Q"
  shows "hoare P (while e (a;(b;c))) Q"
using assms 
by simp


(* Some more complex test *)
lemma iftrue [simp]: "denotation_simp (ifthen (λm. True) c) == denotation_simp c" sorry
lemma
  assumes "⋀x. Q x"
  assumes "hoare (λm. P x ∧ Q x) (while P (c;(d;e);(f;g);c)) (λm. m=m)"
  shows "hoare (λm. P x) (while P (c;(d;e);ifthen (λm. m=m) (f;g;c))) (λm. True)"
using assms
apply simp (* Hmm. Only partially simplified... The assoc rule is not applied to the result of the iftrue rule *)
by simp (* Rerunning simp solves the goal *)
(* By the way: "using assms by auto" solves the goal in one go *)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my implementation of the [suggestions by Andreas Lochbihler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30589667/2646248). The first part is a generic implementation (suitable for other equivalences than denotational equivalence), and below it is instantiated for my example Hoare logic.

```
(* Written by Dominique Unruh *)
theory Test2
imports Main
begin

section "Implementation of modulo-simplifier"


definition fun_equiv :: "('a ⇒ 'b) ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" where "fun_equiv f x y == f x = f y"
lemma fun_equiv_refl: "fun_equiv f x x" by(simp add: fun_equiv_def)

ML {*
(* Call as: hoare_simproc_tac (simplifications@congruences) context/simpset *)
fun fun_equiv_simproc_tac intros ctxt =
  SUBGOAL (fn (goal,i) =>
    case goal of
      Const(@{const_name Trueprop},_) $ (Const(@{const_name fun_equiv},_)$_$_$_) => 
        (resolve0_tac intros THEN_ALL_NEW fun_equiv_simproc_tac intros ctxt) i
        ORELSE (rtac @{thm fun_equiv_refl} i)
    | _ => 
        SOLVED' (simp_tac ctxt) i)

fun fun_equiv_simproc start intros _ ctxt (t:cterm) = 
  let val fresh_var = Var(("x",Term.maxidx_of_term (Thm.term_of t)+1),Thm.typ_of_cterm t)
      val goal = Logic.mk_equals (Thm.term_of t,fresh_var)
      val thm = Goal.prove ctxt [] [] goal 
                (fn {context,...} => resolve0_tac start 1 THEN ALLGOALS (fun_equiv_simproc_tac intros context))
  in 
    if (Thm.rhs_of thm) aconvc t then NONE else SOME thm
  end
  handle ERROR msg => (warning ("fun_equiv_simproc failed\nTerm was:\n"^(@{make_string} t)^"\nError: "^msg); NONE)

fun fun_equiv_simproc_named start cong simp morph ctxt =
  fun_equiv_simproc (Named_Theorems.get ctxt start) (Named_Theorems.get ctxt simp @ Named_Theorems.get ctxt cong) morph ctxt
*}

section "Minimal Hoare logic"

(* A simple language and Hoare logic *)
typedecl program
typedecl memory
consts
  seq :: "program ⇒ program ⇒ program" (infixl ";" 100) (* c;d: run c, then run d *)
  ifthen :: "(memory ⇒ bool) ⇒ program ⇒ program" (* ifthen e c: run c if e(current_mem)=true *)
  while :: "(memory ⇒ bool) ⇒ program ⇒ program" (* while e c: run c while e(current_mem)=true *)
  denotation :: "program ⇒ memory ⇒ memory"  (* denotation c m: memory after running c, when starting with memory m *)
  hoare :: "(memory ⇒ bool) ⇒ program ⇒ (memory ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool" 
      (* hoare P c Q: if P(current_mem), then after running c, we have Q(current_mem) *)

section "Instantiating the simplifier"

named_theorems denot_simp_start
named_theorems denot_simp
named_theorems denot_cong

lemma hoare_cong_start [denot_simp_start]: "fun_equiv denotation c c' ⟹ hoare P c Q == hoare P c' Q" sorry
lemma while_cong [denot_cong]: "fun_equiv denotation c c' ⟹ fun_equiv denotation (while b c) (while b c')" sorry
lemma seq_cong [denot_cong]: "fun_equiv denotation a a' ⟹ fun_equiv denotation b b' ⟹ fun_equiv denotation (a ; b) (a' ; b')" sorry
lemma if_cong [denot_cong]: "fun_equiv denotation c c' ⟹ fun_equiv denotation (ifthen b c) (ifthen b c')" sorry
lemma seq_assoc [denot_simp]: "fun_equiv denotation (a ; (b ; c)) (a; b; c)" sorry
lemma ifthen_true [denot_simp]: "(⋀m. e m) ⟹ fun_equiv denotation (ifthen e c) c" sorry
lemma double_while [denot_simp]: "(⋀m. e m = e' m) ⟹ fun_equiv denotation c d ⟹ fun_equiv denotation (seq (while e c) (while e' d)) (while e c)" sorry

(* -- "If the set of simplification theorems is fixed, we can use the following setup"
  lemmas hoare_congruences = while_cong if_cong seq_cong
  lemmas hoare_simps = ifthen_true seq_assoc double_while
  simproc_setup hoare_simproc ("hoare P c Q") = {* fun_equiv_simproc @{thms hoare_cong_start} @{thms hoare_simps hoare_congruences} *}
*)


(* To make use of dynamic lists of theorems, we use the following setup *)
simproc_setup hoare_simproc ("hoare P c Q") = {* 
  fun_equiv_simproc_named @{named_theorems denot_simp_start}
                          @{named_theorems denot_cong}
                          @{named_theorems denot_simp}
*}

section "Tests"

(* Testing the simplifier rules *)
lemma
  assumes "hoare P (while e (a;b;c)) Q"
  shows "hoare P (while e (a;(b;c))) Q ∧ True"
using assms 
by simp

lemma 
  assumes "hoare P (while P (c;d;e)) Q"
  assumes "⋀x. P x = R x"
  shows "hoare P ((while P (c;(d;e))); (while R ((c;d);e))) Q"
using assms by simp

lemma
  assumes "⋀x. Q x"
  assumes "hoare (λm. P x ∧ Q x) (while P (c;(d;e);(f;g);c)) (λm. m=m)"
  shows "hoare (λm. P x) (while P (c;(d;e);ifthen (λm. m=m) (f;g;c))) (λm. True)"
using assms by simp

(* Test: Disabling the simproc *)
lemma
  assumes "hoare P (a;(b;c)) Q"
  shows   "hoare P (a;(b;c)) Q ∧ True"
using[[simproc del: hoare_simproc]] -- "Without this, proof fails"
apply simp
by (fact assms)
end
```